# Filtering a collection using Checkboxes

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Let's say I have a collection called `Cars`, holding a large amount of documents.

Let's say I have 5 `<input type="checkbox">`, each corresponding to the `color` key in a `Cars` document.

I want to query the collection using selectors depending on which checkboxes are selected. What is the best possible solution to this problem? Right now it just seems like I'm going to be writing a lot of `if` statements. Is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can store the selected (checked) set of colors in a Session variable, and use the value of that Session variable in the helper that returns the Cars.  A complete solution is given below.  Save these two files in a new project as `cars.html` and `cars.js`.

```html
<body>
  {{> filter}}
  {{> carList}}
</body>

<template name="filter">
  {{#each colors}}
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="{{.}}" {{checked}} /> {{.}}
    </label>
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="carList">
  <ul>
    {{#each cars}}
      <li>{{make}} {{color}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

```js
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Cars = new Meteor.Collection(null);

  Meteor.startup(function () {
    Cars.remove({});
    Cars.insert({make: 'toyota', color: 'red'});
    Cars.insert({make: 'subaru', color: 'green'});
    Cars.insert({make: 'ford', color: 'brown'});
    Cars.insert({make: 'honda', color: 'white'});
    Cars.insert({make: 'datsun', color: 'yellow'});
    Cars.insert({make: 'doge', color: 'yellow'});
  });

  // return a unique list of colors from the Cars collection
  Template.filter.colors = function () {
    return _.uniq(Cars.find().map(function (car) { return car.color; }));
  };

  Session.setDefault('colors', []);

  // if any checkbox was clicked, map across all checked inputs, and
  // store resulting array of colors in session variable
  Template.filter.events({
    'click input[type=checkbox]': function (ev, tpl) {
      var colors = tpl.$('input:checked').map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
      });
      Session.set('colors', $.makeArray(colors));
    }
  });

  // attribute helper for checked colors
  Template.filter.checked = function () {
    if (_.contains(Session.get('colors'), this.toString())) {
      return {checked: true};
    }
  };

  // return all cars with that have a color in the session variable
  Template.carList.cars = function () {
    return Cars.find({color: {$in: Session.get('colors')}});
  };

}
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan, the mapping of the checkboxes is exactly what I needed.